# Why won't my circles display in "pixel" units?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of circles defined as

```
 nodes = [{
    x: xRange(xvalue),
    y: yRange(getY(xvalue)),
    ... 
}]

vis.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(nodes)
 .enter().append("circle")
 .attr("class", "nodes")
 .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
.attr("cy", function (d) {
    return d.y;
})
.attr("r", "7px")
.attr("fill", "black")
.attr("transform", function (p) {
    return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
})
```

I'm trying to keep the coordinates of the points in "pixel" units as opposed to "axis" units. The only problem is that my points won't display unless they are in "axis" units for some reason. Here are test cases to illustrate this:

[Pixel Units](https://jsfiddle.net/qzbhLe0d/8/)

[Axis Units](https://jsfiddle.net/qzbhLe0d/11/)

In both cases, I have included a test point in the first quadrant, which uses "pixel" units. Is there any reason why the test point can use pixels but the others can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my circles I use the statement

```
.attr("transform", function (p) {
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    })
```

Which is troublesome because it causes the points to translate based on axes units. By changing this to

```
.attr("transform", function (p) {
        return "translate(" + xRange.invert(p.x) + "," + yRange.invert(p.y) + ")";
    })
```

The translations will correctly take pixel units and graph them.

[Proof](https://jsfiddle.net/qzbhLe0d/15/)